# LWC Shared Styles Standard imports not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, shared-css

I am following the official guide here
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_css_share

"styles" is my LWC having shared CSS rules, as explained below:

**styles.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**styles.css**

```
H1 {
    color:red;
}
```

"other" is the LWC which includes "styles" shared component.

**other.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

with other.js and other.html having default markup generated by SFDX plugin

**other.css** tried to import the styles, as shown below

```
@import 'c/styles';
```

Error on deploying other LWC is as follows:

```
=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH                               ERRORS                                                      
─────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
force-app/main/default/lwc/other/other.js  No MODULE named markup://c:styles found : [markup://c:other]
```

I tried in namespace prefixed and nonprefixed orgs both by replacing the **c/styles** with "ns/styles" as well.

Comment: You have to have a styles.js file. Do you have one?

Answer (score 1):

i tried to replicate your issue in my org without a namespace and i was able to do so. Initially i have created a component with just two files:- css and meta.xml file. This component got successfully deployed.

[image]

After creating other component to import the css module, tried to deploy it. Got the same error as you.

[image]

Once i added the js file in style component, The error does not came. The issue got fixed.

[image]

But then component did not worked for me, So i performed the following steps:-

> I deleted again the JS file of the style component and redeployed to
> the org. It worked. In simple word, First deploy the style component
> with JS file, then deploy other component with imported module, then
> deploy the style component without other file.

This is a workaround, not a concrete solution. I think, sfdx team should look into the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Someone shared this link with me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6p3TZCtsYE&feature=youtu.be and it solves the problem easily. It seems to be a bug in Salesforce CLI or Deployment runtime, which is not detecting the dependencies correctly.

To summarise the above video in one line: "One has to deploy the whole LWC folder to get rid of this issue, it will handle all dependencies correctly."